# Single Page Application Security

Tags: angular

Just a random thought, how do  SPA make their sites secure ? I mean all the embedded script are accessible right? People can just download and analyze the code .. Any ideas ?

Plus when connecting to other web services you need to pass certain "keys", where will you put it if you don't want it to be viewed

Comment: Same theory applies as typical web pages, any sensitive information should still be kept server side and called via asynchronous javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In a SPA you will not store any sensitive data. Based on the data you get you can run some client side business login. You can use components to reduce the client-side code and component communication to reduce the backend calls. The main adv is UI/UX performance would be good trying to reduce backend calls.